# LINQ Take and Where order of operations deterministic?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have an in-memory `IEnumerable` (IE, database is not involved). Will the following query *always* execute in the order I'm asking it to? Or do I need to call another `ToList()` after the `Take()` for it to be deterministic? For context, I'm doing this because I want to know whether I should be showing a "Load More" button, so I'm asking for one more element than I actually need.

```
int pageSize = 50;

// instantiated elsewhere. database call materialized with ToList() prior to returning
IEnumerable<object> objects = GetMyObjects(pageSize + 1); 

// will return 51, for example
int objectCount = objects.Count();

// should now return 50
objects = objects.Take(pageSize);

// will filter further, but from the above 50
objects = objects.Where(object => object.SomeBooleanProperty);

// now should only order after the above filtering is done
objects = objects.OrderByDescending(object => object.SomeDateProperty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `GetMyObjects` returns a sorted list, these LINQ queries will be deterministic. They will always run in the order that you wrote them in.

There isn't a need to call `ToList()` after the `Take` call. All that will do is materialize the results into a `List`, but it should act the same regardless.

LINQ statements are lazily executed, which means you write `Take`, `Where` and `OrderByDescending`, but they aren't executed until something iterates or materializes the `IEnumerable` (i.e. Calling `ToList()`). They'll be executing in
order.

The place where you can get into trouble is if an `IEnumerable` coming from the database is materialized multiple times, it can cause the same query to be unintentionally executed multiple times. Since the database is stateful, it can return different results every time.

For instance:

```csharp
IEnumerable<Thing> things = GetThingsFromDatabase(); // Does NOT call ToList()

var list1 = things.ToList();
var list2 = things.ToList(); // May run query AGAIN, which might have different results.
```

But, as you said, `GetMyObjects` calls `ToList`, you're working with a stable list of objects in memory.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the fast answer :)

Comment: Sure. Also here's a fiddle you can experiment with if you wish: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmQrxr